# Get Kunena Avatar in a custom module

Tags: joomla

I´m using the forum extension kunena for Joomla 3.0. Now i need to get the users kunena avatar in a custom module. How can i call it with php.

I tried sth. like that

```
<?php
require_once (KUNENA_PATH_LIB . '/kunena.login.php');
$avatar = CKunenaLogin::getMyAvatar();
echo $avatar;
?>
```

Comment: and what happened when you did that?

Answer (score 0):

I used this code

```
if (class_exists('KunenaFactory')) {
    $user = KunenaFactory::getUser(JFactory::getUser()->id);
    $avatar = $user->getAvatarImage('', $width, $height);
}
```